# Check if $n=m^2$ in $\mathbb F_q$

Tags: number-theory, congruences

I'm studying elliptic curves in finite fields, and seeing an algorithm to find points of the curve, there's a point in which I have o check if an element $z\in\mathbb F_q$ is a square number, being $q$ an odd power of a prime.

I've seen it can be easily checked this way, we compute:
$$z^{(q-1)/2}$$
if it's $1$, then it's a square, if it's $-1$, it's not.

I can't see why this works. I've tried first seeing the implication that if it's a square, that equality must hold, i.e. if $z=n^2$:
$$n^{q-1}\equiv1\mod q$$

Any hints?

Comment: You should be slightly careful with your notation. Working in $\mathbb F_q$ is not the same as working $\bmod q$, unless $q$ is a prime itself.

Comment: @Engloutie right, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume $q$ is odd as this seem to be the relevant case. $\mathbb{F}_q^\times$ is a cyclic group of order $q-1$. So pick a generator $a$ then every element which is of the form $(a^2)^n$ are squares and the ones which are not of this form are non-squares (official term is quadratic residue and non-quadratic residue)

As there is even split of squares and non-squares and noting $x^{q-1}-1=(x^{(q-1)/2}+1)(x^{(q-1)/2}-1)$ we have the result.

This result is known as Euler's Criterion and I take you must have seen this before but forgot about it if you are studying elliptic curve :).